# Jquery Image Border on Radio Select

Tags: jquery, css, image, radio-button, border

I am trying to tie an border image to appear when you select a radio box. Here is the code:

```
<table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" id="option_img"><br><input class="optionVent" type="radio" name="vent" value="1">vent</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" id="option_img"><br><input class="optionVent" type="radio" name="vent" value="1">vent</td>
                    </tr></table>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
$(".optionVent").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#option_img").css('border', "solid 1px orange"); 
    }  
});
```

As it stands now, when 1 box is selected, both images get borders. I can't figure out a way to tie the images to the radio selection box.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".optionVent").on('change', function(){
    $('img').css('border', 'none'); //add a class to be more specific
    $(this).closest('td').find('img').css('border', 'solid 1px orange'); 
});
```

Also, ID's are unique, you can only have one of each ID, not several.

Comment: That works great!!! but how do I add if the border disappear if another radio box is checked? I tried this:`$(this).closest('td').find('img').css('border', "none");`  But it doesn't work

Comment: just add removal of the border etc.

Comment: Changed it a bit, try that!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to your stylesheet like `.selected_img { border: solid 1px orange; }` then edit your code and markup to something like this:

### HTML

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="img_box">
            <label for="vent1">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" id="option_img1" /><br>
                <input class="optionVent radio_img1" type="radio" name="vent" id="vent1" value="1" />
                vent one
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div class="img_box">
            <label for="vent2">
                <img src="img/option/collar.png" width="100px" id="option_img2" /><br>
                <input class="optionVent radio_img2" type="radio" name="vent" id="vent2" value="1" />
                vent two
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### JS

```
$(".optionVent").change(function() {
    $('.img_box').removeClass('selected_img');
    $(this).closest('.img_box').addClass('selected_img');
});
```

### CSS

```
.img_box {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
.selected_img {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

I like adding classes instead of including styling in **javascript** so that you can edit all your styling in your **CSS**.

---

## DEMO

Click for [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/57QRG/)

Answer (score 0):

The best logic would be to use CSS to achieve the border and simply use jQuery to add/remove that class to the selected elements. This keeps the CSS styling separates from the HTML content, which is how it should be.

```
$(".optionVent").click (function {
  // First, go up two levels and back down one to remove the classes
  $(this).parent().parent().children().removeclass("selected");

  // Secondly, add the class to the parent element
  $(this).parent().addclass("selected");
});
```

Your CSS would then be:

```
.selected {
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
```

You can modify this as needed to get the desired effect.